# Creating a column that indicates when a change in values happens by ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I know this is simple but I am having a little trouble trying to see when someone switche
s roles.
df

```
 ID     Date         Job 
101     05/2022      Sales 
101     06/2022      Sales 
102     12/2021      Tech    
102     1/2022       Tech 
102     2/2022       Finance 
103     4/2022       HR 
103     5/2022       Sales 
103     6/2022       Tech
```

Desired output:

```
ID     Date       Job      Switch 
101    05/2022    Sales      No 
101    06/2022    Sales      No 
102    12/2021    Tech       No 
102    01/2022     Tech       No 
102    02/2022     Finance    Yes 
103    04/2022     HR         No 
103    05/2022     Sales      Yes 
103    06/2022     Tech       Yes
```

I believe the right approach would be starting with `df.groupby('ID')[Job']` Any suggestions?

Comment: What if the Job comes back to the original Job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, use `shift()` on the groupby:

```
mask = df.groupby(['ID'])['Job'].shift().fillna(df['Job']).ne(df['Job'])
df['Switch'] = np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
    ID     Date      Job Switch
0  101  05/2022    Sales     No
1  101  06/2022    Sales     No
2  102  12/2021     Tech     No
3  102   1/2022     Tech     No
4  102   2/2022  Finance    Yes
5  103   4/2022       HR     No
6  103   5/2022    Sales    Yes
7  103   6/2022     Tech    Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group and then use the shift, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103],
    'Date': ['05/2022', '06/2022', '12/2021', '01/2022', '02/2022', '04/2022', '05/2022', '06/2022'],
    'Job': ['Sales', 'Sales', 'Tech', 'Tech', 'Finance', 'HR', 'Sales', 'Tech']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by 'ID' and compare current row's job with previous row's job
df['Switch'] = df.groupby('ID')['Job'].apply(lambda x: x != x.shift())
df['Switch'] = df['Switch'].map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`grouby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Switch'] = df['Job'].ne(df.groupby('ID')['Job'].transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
    ID     Date      Job  Switch
0  101  05/2022    Sales   False
1  101  06/2022    Sales   False
2  102  12/2021     Tech   False
3  102   1/2022     Tech   False
4  102   2/2022  Finance    True
5  103   4/2022       HR   False
6  103   5/2022    Sales    True
7  103   6/2022     Tech    True
```

If you want Yes/No:

```
df['Switch'] = np.where(df['Job'].ne(df.groupby('ID')['Job'].transform('first')),
                        'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
    ID     Date      Job Switch
0  101  05/2022    Sales     No
1  101  06/2022    Sales     No
2  102  12/2021     Tech     No
3  102   1/2022     Tech     No
4  102   2/2022  Finance    Yes
5  103   4/2022       HR     No
6  103   5/2022    Sales    Yes
7  103   6/2022     Tech    Yes
```

Comment: I don't think `transform('first')` is the solution. I'd bet OP expects a different outcome when line `7` is `Sales`...

Comment: Thus my question to OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` and a custom function:

```
has_switched = lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=x.iloc[0]).ne(x)

df['Switch'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Job']
                  .transform(has_switched)
                  .replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID     Date      Job Switch
0  101  05/2022    Sales     No
1  101  06/2022    Sales     No
2  102  12/2021     Tech     No
3  102   1/2022     Tech     No
4  102   2/2022  Finance    Yes
5  103   4/2022       HR     No
6  103   5/2022    Sales    Yes
7  103   6/2022     Tech    Yes
```